# Manually add text for classification in react-image-annotate

Tags: reactjs

I am planning to use [react-image-annotate](https://github.com/UniversalDataTool/react-image-annotate) to annotate images by drawing polygons. But `react-image-annotate` by default only allows selecting a classification from a predefined list.

I wanted something like this library [react-image-annotation](https://secretmapper.github.io/react-image-annotation/) where you can draw a bounding box and it shows you a field in which you can enter custom text.

The documentation says it is possible to build a custom form using `RegionEditLabel`, but there is no clear documentation for it.

Comment: you can use enabledTools={[ "create-polygon",]} to create poligon

Answer (score 1):

If you can live without polygons, the I think the react-picture-annotation might be your answer:

[npmjs: react-picture-annotation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-picture-annotation)

You can draw rectangles, and annotate them with any custom tag you want.  I made a simple codesandbox based on the code from npmjs:

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-lumiere-4p13ou)

You have to:

- draw a shape
- click on the square
- type a name
- click outside box to save